# CPU version of "torch._C._nn.nll_loss" function

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

Is there a function for torch._C._nn.nll_loss that takes in a CPU input? I don't have enough GPU memory to run my function so I'm trying to run everything on CPU. 
This is my specific error (look at the anaconda files)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plot_parametric_pytorch.py", line 395, in <module>
    val_result = validate(val_loader, model, criterion, 0)
  File "plot_parametric_pytorch.py", line 228, in validate
    training=False, optimizer=None)
  File "plot_parametric_pytorch.py", line 169, in forward
    loss = criterion(output, target_var)
  File "/home/klee/anaconda3/envs/sharpenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 550, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/klee/anaconda3/envs/sharpenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py", line 932, in forward
    ignore_index=self.ignore_index, reduction=self.reduction)
  File "/home/klee/anaconda3/envs/sharpenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 2317, in cross_entropy
    return nll_loss(log_softmax(input, 1), target, weight, None, ignore_index, None, reduction)
  File "/home/klee/anaconda3/envs/sharpenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 2115, in nll_loss
    ret = torch._C._nn.nll_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index)
RuntimeError: Expected object of device type cuda but got device type cpu for argument #1 'self' in call to _thnn_nll_loss_forward
```

Comment: the NLL Loss should be available for cpu and gpu since it is just a function. There should be parts of your code that .to(device), that are supposed to change to cpu

Comment: Oops yeah I found my error, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nll_loss` works for both CPU and GPU, but the input and the target need to be on the same device. Yours are on different devices, where the first one (`output`) is on the CPU, but the second (`target_var`) is on the GPU.

You need to put `target_var` onto the CPU.

```py
loss = criterion(output, target_var.cpu())
```